# Oracle SQL - Select Max Integer Value from UserID String

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select the `MAX` value of the integer associated with the UserID in my Oracle database table to generate the next username for users with similar UserID.

The UserID contains values such as below. There is no fixed pattern of characters before the integer as the string is a username.

```
TKe10
TKe9
TKe12
TomKelly13
TomKelly9
PJames12
PJames7
```

I tried using the query below but it always gives `TKe9` OR `TomKelly9` OR `PJames7` as the `MAX` value.

```
SELECT * FROM 
              (SELECT MAX(UserID) from PV_USERS
              WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (UserID, '^'|| '<some_user_id>'|| '[^A- 
              Za-z][0-9]*'));
```

I have also tried using `ORDER BY DESC WHERE ROWNUM<=1` but it also gives the same output.

Comment: Numbers will only appear at the end. I am expecting only the highest number as the output. The idea is to increment that by 1 and generate the next UserID. About the matches of usernames with same numerals at the end, they won't be checked as the string before the integers are completely different. The MAX integer is required for people with similar UserID for uniqueness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to extract just the numeric part of the ID, which you can do with

```
regexp_substr(userid, '[0-9]*$')
```

and then convert that to a number before finding the maximum (otherwise you'll still be doing string comparison, and sorting 9 before 10):

```
max(to_number(regexp_substr(userid, '[0-9]*$')))
```

and you probably want to allow for the ID root you're checking to not exist at all yet, which you can do with `nvl()` or `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(max(to_number(regexp_substr(userid, '[0-9]*$'))), 0) as max_num
from pv_users
where regexp_like(userid, '^'|| 'TomKelly'|| '[0-9]*');

   MAX_NUM
----------
        13

select coalesce(max(to_number(regexp_substr(userid, '[0-9]*$'))), 0) as max_num
from pv_users
where regexp_like(userid, '^'|| 'PJames'|| '[0-9]*');

   MAX_NUM
----------
        12

select coalesce(max(to_number(regexp_substr(userid, '[0-9]*$'))), 0) as max_num
from pv_users
where regexp_like(userid, '^'|| 'NewName'|| '[0-9]*');

   MAX_NUM
----------
         0
```

... and then add 1 and append back onto the root to get the next ID.

Depending on your business rules, you *might* want to make the filter case-insensitive.

---

You should be aware that two sessions performing this operation simultaneously will see the same result, so both would try to create the same ID, e.g. `TomKelly14`. You either need to serialise this generation operation, or include a fall back - like checking if you get a PK violation when you try to insert the new value into the table and repeating if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
with temp as
(
select 'Tke10' userid from dual
union all
 select 'Tke9' userid from dual
union all
 select 'Tke12' userid from dual
union all
 select 'Tomkelly13' userid from dual
union all
 select 'Tomkelly9' userid from dual
union all
 select 'Pjames12' userid from dual
union all
 select 'Pjames7' userid from dual
 )

    select A||B from (
 select 
 substr(userid,1,instr(userid,to_number(regexp_substr(userid,'\d+$')))-1) A
,max(to_number(regexp_substr(userid,'\d+$'))) B
from temp
 group by substr(userid,1,instr(userid,to_number(regexp_substr(userid,'\d+$')))-1)
)
 ;
```